# How many tables is too many for a 1 GB Database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 9 tables (total of 43 fields).  I have access to many 1GB MySQL databases.  Should I split my 9 tables over multiple databases or just pile them all into one database?

Comment: I would say keep them all in one database, there's no reason to split them up and it can only be inconvenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how much data is going to be in each table.

A table itself takes up almost no space - it's the rows that make the database size grow.

What you need to do is estimate how large each table is going to get within the foreseeable future - erring on the side of keeping the tables together.

That said, nine tables with 43 fields (assuming reasonably sized rows) would need to have hundreds of thousands of rows each to approach 1GB. I have a multi-million-row SQLite file which is only 100MB.

Comment: Nearly every question in our database lectures has to be answered with 'it depends' ;)

Comment: A good suggest @Borealid.  I have calculated that the database will hit capacity in roughly 20 years, thus, I assume having just one database will do.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

How much data are you expecting?

How much more complicated is it if you have to manage multiple databases?

How much slower will it be to query multiple databases and aggregate the results?

How important is performance?

Putting everything in a single database will give you better performance (usually) and is easier to develop.  You should do that until your data gets big enough that you outgrow the database.